# how to read data using from selected line using streamreader

Tags: c#, sql

i have a data like this

```
Total Size (Media)..........,517.31 GB
Elapsed Time................,4h 32m 26s
Total Size (Media)..........,517.31 GB
Elapsed Time................,4h 37m 31s
Workstation.................,ITPHOFPDENRP01 ( 10.10.156.20 )
Start Time..................,1/06/17
Workstation.................,ITPHOFPDENRP01 ( 10.10.156.20 )
Path........................,D:\Apps
Total Size (Media)..........,27.00 GB
Elapsed Time................,46m 20s
Total Size (Media)..........,27.00 GB
Elapsed Time................,46m 20s
Workstation.................,ITPBACKUP ( 10.10.160.10 )
Start Time..................,1/06/17 10:04 PM
Workstation.................,ITPBACKUP ( 10.10.160.10 )
Path........................,D:\Job
Total Size (Media)..........,204.38 MB
Elapsed Time................,1m 9s
Total Size (Media)..........,204.38 MB
Elapsed Time................,1m 9s
Workstation.................,ITPBACKUP ( 10.10.160.10 )
```

how can i read the data from line start time until the next start time and always like that and the result must like this

`Workstation      Path     Elapsed Time     Total Size (Media)   Start Time`

Comment: You are getting this in csv file or a file like above all the time? Or in the form of a string from calling function?

Comment: no this data i get from text file and that data will export to sql server @anand

Comment: You sure you want to start reading from Start Time till next Start Time and whatever comes in between creates a row for you? I didn't see Start Time as first row in your txt so asked.

Comment: What does "and always like that" mean?

Comment: @JecoAlviano - Your question isn't terribly clear. Can you please show the full expected output given your sample input?

Comment: the output will add into their column @enigmativity

Comment: @JecoAlviano - Yes, I figured that. Can you please show the full expected output given your sample input? i.e. which value fields will appear in each row.

Comment: @JecoAlviano - The output would be good to get.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a class to hold this information. Something like

```
 public class RowData
{
    public string Workstation { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public string TotalSize { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

After that, you read the file and iterate through lines, something like below

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(@"D:\Example1.txt", FileMode.Open);

       List<RowData> lstLines = new List<RowData>();
        using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            RowData oRowData = null;
            while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                string sLine = stRead.ReadLine();
                if (sLine.IndexOf("Start Time") > -1)
                {
                    if (oRowData != null)
                    {
                        lstLines.Add(oRowData);
                        oRowData = null;
                    }
                    oRowData = new RowData();
                    sLine = sLine.Replace(".", "");
                    sLine = sLine.Replace("Start Time", "");
                    oRowData.StartTime = sLine;    
                }
                if (sLine.IndexOf("Workstation") > -1)
                {
                    if (oRowData != null)
                    {
                        sLine = sLine.Replace(".", "");
                        sLine = sLine.Replace("Workstation", "");
                        oRowData.Workstation = sLine;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Once your RowData List is filled, you can use it the way you want...

```
 foreach (var item in lstLines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.StartTime + "|" + item.Workstation);
        }
```

*Please note that, you will have to remove these "." characters*